# ExtJs - populating data from database to grid using actioncolumn

Tags: extjs

I have a grid with actionColumn and when I click on edit icon it should call the other form(already available) with data populated in to fields from database so that the user can edit and save it. I am new to Extjs please help

I tried with the following code but its not working:

```
myForm.getForm().load({
url: '/.RetrieveRecords',
params: { id: id},
method: 'POST',      
waitMsg: 'Loading data...'
```

Here is my form1:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'extjs.com',
    launch : function()
    {
        var myForm  = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',
        {
            title: 'Registration Form',
            id: 'form',
            Layout: 'border',
            border: 'true',
            padding: 10,
            bodyPadding: 30,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items : 
            [
                {fieldLabel: 'First Name', name: 'firstname', id: 'firstname',allowBlank: false, minLength: 2, maxLength:25, regex:/^[a-zA-Z]/},
                {fieldLabel: 'Last Name', name: 'lastname', id: 'lastname', allowBlank: false, minLength: 2, maxLength:25},
                {fieldLabel: 'Email', name: 'email', id: 'email',allowBlank: false, vType: 'email', msgTarget:'under'},
                {fieldLabel: 'Mobile Number', name: 'mobilenumber', id: 'mobilenumber',allowBlank: false, minLength: 10, maxLength:10, regex:/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/, regexText:"Invalid mobile number",msgTarget:"under"},

                {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    fieldLabel: 'DOB'+'<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold" data-qtip="Required">*</span>',
                    name: 'dob',
                    id:'dob',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    value: '2 4 1978',
                    format: 'd m Y',
//                    value: new Date(),
                    maxValue: new Date(),
                    msgTarget:'side'                                
                },
                {
                    xtype:'radiogroup',
                    fieldLabel: 'Gender',
                    defaultType: 'radiofield',
                    anchor: '22.5%',
                    id:'gender1',
                    defaults: 
                            {
                                flex: 1
                            },
                            layout: 'hbox',
                    items: [
                            {
                                boxLabel: 'Male',
                                name: 'rb',
                                inputValue: 'M',
                                checked: true
                            },
                            {
                               boxLabel: 'Female',
                               name: 'rb',
                               inputValue: 'F',
                            }]
                },
                {
                    xtype:'checkboxgroup',
                    fieldLabel: 'Known Technologies',
                    anchor: '50%',
                    id:'tech',
                    columns: 3,
                    vertical: true,
                    items:
                            [
                                {boxLabel: 'java', name: 'cb',inputValue: 'java', x:20, checked: true},
                                {boxLabel: 'c++', name: 'cb',inputValue: 'c++', x:20, checked: true},
                                {boxLabel: 'jsp', name: 'cb',inputValue: 'jsp', x:20, checked: false},
                                {boxLabel: 'javascript', name: 'cb',inputValue: 'javascript', checked: false},
                                {boxLabel: 'hadoop', name: 'cb',inputValue: 'hadoop', checked: false},
                                {boxLabel: 'spring', name: 'cb',inputValue: 'spring', checked: false}
                            ]
                },
                {
                    xtype:'textarea',
                    fieldLabel: 'Hobbies',
                    name:'hobby',
                    id:'hobby',
                    anchor:'100%'
//                    padding:5
                },
                {
                    xtype:'fieldset',
                    title: 'Address',
                    collapsible:false,
                    items:
                            [
                                {
                                xtype:'combobox',
                                displayField:'cname',
                                valueField:'cid',
                                fieldLabel:'country'+'<span style =color:red;data-qtip="Required">*</span>',
                                queryMode:'local',
                                msgTarget: 'under',
                                name:'country',
                                id: 'country',
                                store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
                                fields:['cid','cname']
                                                                   }),
                                    listeners:
                                            {
                                                afterrender:function()
                                                {
                                                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                                        url:'./getRecords',
                                                        success: function(response)
                                                        {
                                                           var jarray = [];
                                                           jarray = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                                                           Ext.getCmp('country').getStore().loadData(jarray);
                                                        },
                                                        failure: function(response)
                                                        {
                                                            Ext.Msg.alert('failed' + response.status);
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                },
                                                change: function(a,b,c)
                                                {
                                                    var countryID1 =  Ext.getCmp('country').getValue();
                                                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                                        url:'./getStates',
                                                        params:{countryID:countryID1},
                                                        success: function(response)
                                                        {
                                                            //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                                                            var jarray = [];
                                                            jarray=Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                                                            Ext.getCmp('state').getStore().loadData(jarray);
                                                        },
                                                        failure: function(response)
                                                        {
                                                            Ext.Msg.alert('Failed' + response.status);
                                                        }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                xtype:'combobox',
                                displayField:'sname',
                                valueField:'sid',
                                fieldLabel:'State',
                                name:'state',
                                id:'state',
                                queryMode:'local',
                                msgTarget: 'under',
                                store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
                                fields:['sid','sname']
                                                                   }),
                                listeners:
                                            {
                                                change: function(a,b,c)
                                                {
                                                    var StateID = Ext.getCmp('state').getValue();
                                                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                                        url:'./getCities',
                                                        params: {StateID1:StateID},
                                                        success: function(response)
                                                        {
                                                            var jarray = [];
                                                            jarray = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                                                            Ext.getCmp('city').getStore().loadData(jarray);
                                                        },
                                                        failure: function(response)
                                                        {
                                                            Ext.Msg.alert('failed' + response.status);
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                }
                                        }                                   
                                },
                                {
                                xtype:'combobox',
                                displayField:'cname',
                                valueField:'cid',
                                fieldLabel:'City',
                                name:'city',
                                id:'city',
                                queryMode:'local',
                                msgTarget: 'under',
                                store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
                                fields:['cid','cname','sid']
                                                                   })
                                },
                                {
                                xtype:'textfield',
                                displayField:'PincodeName',
                                valueField:'pincodeID',
                                fieldLabel:'Pin-code',
                                id:'pincode',
                                allowBlank: false,
                                maskRe: /[0-9\-]/,
                                regex: /^[0-9]{3}(\-)?[0-9]{3}$/,
                                regexText:"invalid pincode",
                                msgTarget: 'under'
                                }
                            ]
                },
                {
                    xtype:'fieldset',
                    title:'Education',
                    collasible: false,
                    items:
                            [
                                {
                                    xtype:'combobox',
                                    displayField:'QualificationName',
                                    valueField:'QualificationID',
                                    fieldLabel:'Qualification',
                                    id:'qualification',
                                    name:'qualification',
                                    queryMode:'local',
                                    msgTarget:'side',
                                    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
                                        fields:['QualificationID','QualificationName'],
                                        data:
                                                [
                                            {"QualificationID":"1","QualificationName":"B.Tech"},
                                            {"QualificationID":"2","QualificationName":"Diploma"},
                                            {"QualificationID":"3","QualificationName":"Advanced Diploma"}
                                                ]
                                                                       }),
                                        listeners: 
                                                {
                                                    change: function()
                                                    {
                                                        Ext.getCmp('DepartmentID').setVisible(true);
                                                        Ext.getCmp('PercentageID').setVisible(true);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                },
                                {
                                xtype:'textfield',
                                name:'department',
                                id:'DepartmentID',
                                displayField:'Department',
                                valueField:'DeptID',
                                fieldLabel:'Department',
                                allowBlank: false,
                                hidden:true,
                                msgTarget: 'under'
                                },
                                {
                                xtype:'textfield',
                                name: 'percentage',
                                id: 'PercentageID',
                                displayField:'Percentage',
                                valueField:'PercentageID',
                                fieldLabel:'Percentage',
                                msgTarget: 'under',
                                regex:/^-?[0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?%?$|^-?(100)(\.[0]{1,2})?%?$/,
                                regexText:"invalid percentage",
                                hidden:true
                                }
                            ]
                }
            ],
            buttons:
                    [
                        {text:'Submit',
                            handler: function()
                            {
                                var mail = Ext.getCmp('email').getValue();
                                var mnumber = Ext.getCmp('mobilenumber').getValue();
                                var gender = Ext.getCmp('gender1').getChecked()[0].inputValue;

                                var selection = [];
                                selection = Ext.getCmp('tech').getChecked();
                                var selections = "";
                                for(var i=0;i<selection.length;i++)
                                {
                                    selections += selection[i].inputValue + " ";
                                }

                                var add = Ext.getCmp('country').getRawValue()+","+Ext.getCmp('state').getRawValue()+","+Ext.getCmp('city').getRawValue()+","+Ext.getCmp('pincode').getValue();
                                var edu = Ext.getCmp('qualification').getRawValue()+","+Ext.getCmp('DepartmentID').getValue()+","+Ext.getCmp('PercentageID').getValue();
                                var dob = Ext.getCmp('dob').getRawValue();
                                var hobby = Ext.getCmp('hobby').getValue();
                                var fname = Ext.getCmp('firstname').getValue();
                                var lname = Ext.getCmp('lastname').getValue();

                                //alert(this.up('form'));

                                var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                                if(form.isValid())
                                {
                                    Ext.Ajax.request
                                    ({
                                        url:'./Save_Records',
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        params: {mail1:mail,mnumber1:mnumber,gender2:gender,selections1:selections,add1:add,edu1:edu,dob1:dob,hobby1:hobby,fname1:fname,lname1:lname},
                                        success: function(response)
                                        {
                                            Ext.Msg.alert("success" + response.status);
                                        },
                                        failure: function(response)
                                        {
                                            Ext.Msg.alert("failed" + response.status);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                 alert("Please fill in the form");
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text:'Reset',
                            handler: function()
                            {
                                this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                                Ext.Ajax.request
                                ({
                                    url:'index.jsp',
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    success: function(response)
                                    {
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success' + " " + response.status);
                                    },
                                    failure: function(response)
                                    {
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failure' + " " + response.status);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    ]
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my Form2 with Actioncolumns:

```
 Ext.onReady(function()
 {
     var store=Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
       {
           autoload: true,
           autosync: true,
           data: [],
           fields:
                   [
                        {name: 'firstname', id:'firstname'},
                        {name: 'email', id:'email'},
                        {name: 'mobileno', id:'mobileno'}
                   ]
       });

     Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',
       {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            height:150,
            width:400,
            x:200,
            y:50,
            store:store,
            id: 'grid1',

                        columns:
                    [
                        {
                            header:'Firstname',
                            id:'firstname',
                            dataIndex:'firstname',
                            editor: {
                                        xtype: 'textarea'
                                    }
                        },
                        {
                            header:'Mobileno',
                            id:'mobileno',
                            dataIndex:'mobileno',
                            editor: {
                                        xtype: 'textarea'
                                    }
                        },
                        {
                            header:'Email',
                            id:'email',
                            dataIndex:'email',
                            editor: {
                                        xtype: 'textarea'
                                    }
                        },
                        {
                            header:'Action',
                            id:'action',
                            align:'center',
                            xtype:'actioncolumn',
                            sortable:false,

                            items:
                                    [
                                        {
                                            icon:'images/view_icon.gif',
                                            tooltip:'View',
                                            handler: function(grid,rowIndex,colIndex)
                                            {
                                                var rec= grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            icon:'images/edit_icon.gif',
                                            tooltip:'Edit',
                                            handler: function(grid,rowIndex,colIndex,e)
                                            {
                                                var rec= grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                                                myForm.getForm().load({
//                                                url: '/path/to/form/data',
                                                params: { id: id},
                                                method: 'POST',      
                                                waitMsg: 'Loading data...'
                                             });
//                                                Ext.Ajax.request(
//                                                {
//                                                    url:'./RetrieveRecords',                                                   
//                                                    success: function(response)
//                                                    {
//                                                        Ext.Msg.alert("success" +" " + response.status);
//                                                        window.location.reload();
//                                                    },
//                                                    failure: function(response)
//                                                    {
//                                                        Ext.Msg.alert("failed" + response.status);
//                                                    }
//                                                });

                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            icon:'images/icons/cancel.png',
                                            tooltip:'Delete',
                                            handler: function(grid,rowIndex,colIndex)
                                            {   
                                                var rec= grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                                                var email = rec.get('email');
                                                Ext.Ajax.request(
                                                {
                                                    url:'./deleteRecords',
                                                    params:{email:email},

                                                    success: function(response)
                                                    {
                                                        Ext.Msg.alert("successfully deleted" +" " + response.status);
                                                        window.location.reload();
                                                    },
                                                    failure: function(response)
                                                    {
                                                        Ext.Msg.alert("failed" + response.status);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                        }
                    ],

                    selType: 'cellmodel',
                    plugins: 
                            [
                                Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', 
                                {
                                clicksToEdit: 1
                                })
                            ],

                   listeners: 
                    {
                        afterrender:function()
                         {
                             Ext.Ajax.request(
                           {
                               params:{email:email},
                               url:'./RetrieveRecords',
                               success: function(response)
                               {  
                                   data = [];
                                   data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                                   Ext.getCmp('grid1').getStore().loadData(data);
                               },
                               failure: function(response)
                               {
                                   Ext.Msg.alert("failure" + " " + response.status);
                               }
                           });
                         }
                    }
       });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following as edit button:

```
handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, e) {
    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
    myForm.loadRecord(rec);
}
```